# Comparing NaN and null returns illogic value

Tags: c#

Why does the following code snippet returns 1:

```
double i = double.NaN;
double? i2 = null;
i.CompareTo(i2);
```

From my point of view it makes no sense.
An Exception would be more appropriate.

What do you think was the reasoning behind the decision.

Comment: It forces all the nulls and nans to either the top or the bottom of a list when sorting. The "sense" in sorting nulls and nans is exactly as you state: a point of view. I would guess that it was safer to handle this because `IComparer / IComparable` drives a lot of things in the background, and can most of the time be overridden by the user if they want different behaviour anyway.

Comment: Something is better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation on [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyxd1d26.aspx):

> The value parameter must be null or an instance of Double; otherwise,
>   an exception is thrown. Any instance of Double, regardless of its
>   value, is considered greater than null.

The value parameter in your example is `null`. `NaN` is therefore considered greater than null which is why `CompareTo` correctly returns `1`.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN documentation on `IComparable.CompareTo()`:

> > By definition, any object compares greater than (or follows) null, and two null references compare equal to each other.

This is also apparent from the `Double.CompareTo(object)` documentation:

> > Returns a positive integer if  This instance is greater than value. -or- This instance is a number and value is not a number (NaN). -or- value is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).

As Adam Houldsworth points out, if `something.CompareTo(somethingElse)` threw an exception when somethingElse is null, then sorting and things like that would require lots of extra exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

When you decompile `CompareTo` of `double`, you can see:

```
public int CompareTo(object value)
{
  if (value == null)
    return 1;
```

just to put null elements at the bottom of any sorted sequence.